FDR adjustment for confidence intervals
I have a multiple regression model in R, and I'm supposed to report the beta estimates, 95 CIs, and p-values. There are a lot of variables in the model so I used the Benjamini-Hochberg method to adjust the p-values. However, now the CIs and the adjusted p-values do not match; there are variables whose 95% CIs do not include zero but the adjusted p-values are insignificant.
I wonder how I can adjust the CIs for FDR. Can I use the adjusted p-values to reverse-engineer the CIs using the procedure described in this article below?
https://www.bmj.com/content/343/bmj.d2090
Thanks!

You just need to calculate 1-p % intervals instead of 95%.

Wow! Never thought it was this simple. Thank you!
